# Pinging several servers in the same time

Tags: c#, ping

I have a listview and i try to add server information with this code:

```
foreach(string element in ids)
{
   int id = Int32.Parse(element);
   ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(name[id]);
   item.SubItems.Add(ip[id]);
   Ping pingsv = new Ping();
   PingReply pingreply = pingsv.Send(ips[id],500);
   if (pingreply.RoundtripTime == 0)
       item.SubItems.Add("500+");
   else
       item.SubItems.Add(pingreply.RoundtripTime.ToString());
}
```

But the problem is that the program ping the servers one by one and it takes a lot of time to complete(i have like 80 ip's to ping and there might be more in the future)
So is there any way to ping all the ips in the same time?

Comment: You could use multiple threads.

Comment: Crono, tried but didn't work. Program freezes without any error.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code to see why it freezes?

Comment: Crono, An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll, error appears at Application.Run(new LauncherTest());

Comment: That's not nearly enough information. Edit your question with your multithreading code and the full exception stack trace and we'll take it from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Ping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class you may use an asynchronous event:

```
foreach(string element in ids)
{
   int id = Int32.Parse(element);
   ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(name[id]);
   item.SubItems.Add(ip[id]);
   Ping pingsv = new Ping();
   pingsv.PingCompleted += pingsv_PingCompleted;

   pingsv.SendAsync(IPAddress, 500, id);

}

[... somewhere else in the same class ...]

void pingsv_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
      long pingtime = e.Reply.RoundtripTime;
      // do something with pingtime...

      // id has been saved to UserState (see above)
      string id = (string)e.UserState;

      // do something with id...

}
```

EDIT: Added code to show the possiblity to add arbitary data / objects.

Comment: +1, but careful with this. It could end up using more threads than the process can handle.

Comment: How can I get the id from the foreach in pingsv_PingCompleted function?